# Как узнать, сколько одинаковых элементов в списке?

Tags: python, список

Подскажите пожалуйста как узнать сколько в списке элементов с определенным именем, например Иван. Или сколько людей с одинаковой фамилией.

```
l=['Круглов Алексей', 'Ворожейкин Борис', 'Митин  Сергей', 'Алешин Сергей']


name=l.count('Сергей')
```

Этот метод не срабатывает для части слова,нашел вот такое решение:

```
print(sum(map(lambda x:1 if 'Сергей' in x else 0, l)))
```

Но это пока не мой уровень)), нужно что то простое, без циклов. Спасибо.

Comment: Постановка задачи выглядит, как: "решите мне домашку так, чтобы учитель не догадался, что я не сам решил". Тут приходят со своими решениями и просят помочь их исправить, если не работает.

Comment: "сколько людей с одинаковой фамилией" - это вообще отдельная задача, у вас везде фамилия первым словом идёт? Ну тогда делите "фамилию имя" по пробелу, делайте словарь фамилия:счётчик и считайте.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а как Вы без циклов собираетесь обрабатывать список, если приведенный Вами пример вас не устраивает, по причине того, что это для Вас сложно. Могу предложить рекурсию, но боюсь Вас это тоже не утроит по той же причине

Comment: к циклам еще не дошли, она сказала есть простое решение, но надо перебирать каждую фамилию или имя вручную, пол дня уже сижу с этим)

Comment: Функции, как я понимаю, тоже не проходили?

Comment: это не домашка, просто я пытаюсь понять как это можно сделать имея тот материалл который преподаватель дал на данный момент........да функции тоже не проходили)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю фамилии записать в отдельный список)))

```py
from collections import Counter
my_list = ['анна', 'петя', 'анна', 'петя', 'сережа', 'алена']
result= Counter(my_list)
    
print('**',result)

# ** Counter({'анна': 2, 'петя': 2, 'сережа': 1, 'алена': 1})
```

Comment: В исходнике сложнее ситуевина, там элементы списка не имена

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому, что циклы вы ещё не проходили, то предложу "глупый" вариант:

```
name_list = ['Круглов Алексей', 'Ворожейкин Борис', 'Митин  Сергей', 'Алешин Сергей']
if 'Сергей' in name_list[0]:
    print(name_list[0])
if 'Сергей' in name_list[1]:
    print(name_list[1])
if 'Сергей' in name_list[2]:
    print(name_list[2])
if 'Сергей' in name_list[3]:
    print(name_list[3])
```

Но я бы всё же вам рекомендовал что-то типо такого:

```
name_list = ['Круглов Алексей', 'Ворожейкин Борис', 'Митин  Сергей', 'Алешин Сергей']
for name in name_list:
    if 'Сергей' in name:
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension решает в одну строку

```py
l=['Круглов Алексей', 'Ворожейкин Борис', 'Митин  Сергей', 'Алешин Сергей']
result = len([i for i in l if "Сергей" in i])
```

Результат будет длина списка, в каждом члене которого есть `Сергей`

То же самое, но на "понятном" языке

```py
>>> counter = 0
>>> for item in l:
...   if "Сергей" in item:
...     counter += 1
... 
>>> counter
2
```